# Print looped int as a string

Tags: go

I have a custom type looped to display all of the fields given. The purpose of this is to be able to format it a little better than a long, endless single line. However, printing it within the loop won't work, everything I've tried simply prints a string of a single line versus all 4 from the array.

```golang
type Rule struct {
    Value string `json:"value"`
    Tag   string `json:"tag"`
    Id    string `json:"id"`
}

func test() string {
    get, err := getRules()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, r := range get {
        fmt.Printf("value:%v, tag:%v, id:%v\n", r.Value, r.Tag, r.Id)
    }

    // need to return it as a string like below
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", list)
}
```

is there a way to easily create a variable `list` out of that? So I can display it as a string? That prints:

```
value:x0, tag:t0, id:i0
value:x1, tag:t1, id:i1
value:x2, tag:t2, id:i2
value:x3, tag:t3, id:i3
```

from `fmt.Printf(get)`

```
[{x0 t0 i0} {x1 t1 i1} {x2 t2 i2} {x3 t3 i3}]
```

I'm essentially trying to convert a custom type to a string so that I can display it better.

Comment: why not just use return fmt.Sprintf("%v",get) instead of the loop?

Comment: I need to format ```get``` somehow and I'm having trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement `String` method.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Rule struct {
    Value string `json:"value"`
    Tag   string `json:"tag"`
    Id    string `json:"id"`
}

func (g *Rule) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("value:%s, tag:%s id:%s\n", g.Value, g.Tag, g.Id)
}

type RuleList []Rule

func (g RuleList) String() string {
    slist := make([]string, 0)
    for _, v := range g {
        slist = append(slist, v.String())
    }
    return strings.Join(slist, "")
}

func main() {
    g1 := Rule{Value: "hello", Tag: "1", Id: "1"}
    g2 := Rule{Value: "hello", Tag: "1", Id: "1"}
    g3 := Rule{Value: "hello", Tag: "1", Id: "1"}

    glist := RuleList{g1, g2, g3}

    fmt.Println(glist)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by implementing Stringers interface [more about [Stringers]](https://tour.golang.org/methods/17)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Dummy struct{
    Value, Tag, Id string
}

func (r Dummy) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("value:%v, tag:%v, id:%v\n", r.Value, r.Tag, r.Id)
}

func main(){
    ls := make([]Dummy,0)
    ls = append(ls, Dummy{"x0", "t0", "i0"})
    ls = append(ls, Dummy{"x1", "t1", "i1"})
    ls = append(ls, Dummy{"x2", "t2", "i2"})
    ls = append(ls, Dummy{"x3", "t3", "i3"})

    fmt.Println(Dummy{"x0", "t0", "i0"})
    fmt.Println(ls)
}
```